# Dummy log4j configuration (for tests)

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to configure log4j from java code in simple way - as a result I would like all logs to be written to stdout?

Comment: it is possible and rather simple, but using a log4j.properties file is still simpler. When testing you just use a different file (for example by setting the environment variable, see log4j docs on how to do this)

Comment: Nice point! Anyway, could you please describe the way how can I do it from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NewMain1.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    logger.info("out");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Log4j has a ConsoleAppender to redirect the logs to console. Here is a sample config:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();
root.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(
    new PatternLayout(PatternLayout.TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN)));
```